# error: there is no parameter $1

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I get "error: there is no parameter $1" when I try to run this code using the [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) client:

```
app.post('/newcause', function (req,res){
  console.log(req.body);

  var g;

  var r = [];

  for (g in req.body)
  {
    r[g]=req.body[g];
    console.log('r[g] is ' + r[g]);
  }

  client = pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    client.query('INSERT INTO causes (cause_name, goal, organization, sponsor, submitter) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)', r, function(err){
      console.log('This is r' + r)
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });    
  });
});
```

Any advice?

PS, This is the full error statement:

```
{ [error: there is no parameter $1]
  name: 'error',
  length: 87,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P02',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '81',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  file: 'parse_expr.c',
  line: '812',
  routine: 'transformParamRef' }
```

Comment: What is `r`? Where are you passing the five query parameters?

Comment: I edited to include more info about r.

Comment: It seems like `req.body` is not what you expect it to be. Show us the POST you use from the client to invoke all of this.

Comment: The entire POST or just req.body? Here's req.body:
{ causename: 'Testname',
  Goal: 'TestGoal',
  Organization: 'TestOrg',
  sponsor: 'TestSponsor',
  submitterEmail: 'TestEmail' }

Comment: Shouldn't this be passed to the database as an array (not named key-value pairs)?

Comment: It is r is the array req.body are the key-value pairs

Comment: req.body is an object. It has key-value pairs which you are iterating with `for in`. Are all the names in the form as indexes 0,1,2,3... ?

Comment: No the names are the keys. I iterate the object into an array by doing this:
  for (g in req.body)
  {
    r[g]=req.body[g];
    console.log('r[g] is ' + r[g]);
  }
Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error from executing your query means that `r` is not getting populated correctly. It's worth being explicit about user input so your system doesn't raise an error downstream (in the query) rather than at the problem root:

```
app.post('/newcause', function (req,res){
  console.log(req.body);

  var g;

  var r = [];

  r.push(req.body.causename, req.body.Goal, req.body.Organization, req.body.sponsor, req.body.submitterEmail);

  client = pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    client.query('INSERT INTO causes (cause_name, goal, organization, sponsor, submitter) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)', r, function(err){
      console.log('This is r' + r.toString())
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });    
  });
});
```

It's also worth mentioning that it might be a good idea to standardize your variable name-casing in the post submission.

Comment: Thanks! This worked but I'm unsure why. Wondering what was wrong with my loop . . .

Comment: You can't populate `r` (of type `Array`) as if it's of type `Object`, which is what you're doing. The way you're populating the array won't create a zero-based index of elements, ie. you won't be able to access elements r[0]...r[4] because 0-4 aren't the indexes.